# multivariable calculus - curl, conservative function, etc..

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Multivariable Calculus- Can someone help me ? On the problem attached in the image, I cannot get the same answer : zero.

Which topic should I look up on solving this issue?

Please help.

https://nimb.ws/f3Gdhz

Answer (score 0):

The topic is "line integral": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

It is also important to understand (eventually) the physics behind it: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_03.html

Comment: Thank you.   The Caltech article, which I could not find in the past, is good and well written. On the other hand, I  wonder what your answer will be and if you come up with the same answer ,"zero" as shown in the solution in the image.

Comment: I am getting a zero as well.  Here is how: parameterize the semi-circle by: $x(t) = \cos(t), y(t)=0, z(t) = \sin(t)$, $\pi < t < 2\pi$.  Then
$$
F = (0, \cos^3(t), \cos^2(t)),
$$
and
$$
dr = (-\sin(t), 0, \cos(t)) dt,
$$
so
$$
F \cdot dr = \cos^3(t),
$$
which (noting that $t = 3\pi/4$ is the midpoint of our integration interval) has the property of being odd w.r.t. that midpoint:
$$
\cos^3(t - 3 \pi/4) = - \cos^3(-t - 3 \pi/4),
$$
so the integral is zero.

Comment: Great explanations! Thanks a lot!

Comment: $3 \pi/2$, not $3\pi /4$.